# Plotly Dash server side caching using redis

Tags: python, flask, caching, redis, plotly-dash

I am trying to replicate example 4 in [this part](https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks) of the Plotly Dash documentation, using redis cache instead. I am not sure how to configure the cache properly. Assuming that I have my redis DB set up, is it enough to add:

```
cache = Cache(app.server, config={
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'redis',
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': redis_url,
    'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 450
})
```

What happens if I want to use `CACHE_THRESHOLD`? Is this not necessary? (reading the [flask cache documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/) it seems like this parameter is not used for redis).

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? Curios to know how you did.

Comment: @Dre it works just fine as configured in the question, assuming that your redis instance is up and running and that you can connect to it without any issues. There’s no need to provide a cache threshold.